# Mirror only files having specific string in file path

Tags: regex, wildcard, wget, mirroring, lftp

I'm trying to mirror only those branches of a directory tree that contain a specific directory name somewhere within the branch. I've spent several hours trying different things to no avail.

A remote FTP site has a directory structure like this:

```
image_db
  movies
    v2
      20131225
        xyz
          xyz.jpg
      20131231
        abc
          abc.jpg
      AllPhotos   <-- this is what I want to mirror
        xyz
          xyz.jpg
        abc
          abc.jpg
    v4
      (similar structure to 'v2' above, contains 'AllPhotos')
    ...
  tv_shows
    (similar structure to 'movies', contains 'AllPhotos')
  other
    (different paths, some of which contain 'AllPhotos')
  ...
```

I am trying to create a local mirror of only the 'AllPhotos' directories, with their parent paths intact.

I've tried variations of this:

`lftp -e 'mirror --only-newer --use-pget-n=4 --verbose -X /* -I AllPhotos/ /image_db/ /var/www/html/mir_images' -u username,password ftp.example.com`

...where the "-X /*" excludes all directories and "-I AllPhotos/" includes only AllPhotos. This doesn't work, lftp just copies everything.

I also tried variations of this:

`lftp -e 'glob -d -- mirror --only-newer --use-pget-n=4 --verbose /image_db/*/*/AllPhotos/ /var/www/html/mir_images' -u username,password ftp.example.com`

...and lftp crunches away at the remote directory structure without actually creating anything on my side.

Basically, I want to mirror only those files that have the string 'AllPhotos' somewhere in the full directory path.

**Update 1:**

If I can do this with wget, rsync, ftpcopy or some other utility besides lftp, I welcome suggestions for alternatives.

Trying wget didn't work for me either:

`wget -m -q -I /image_db/*/*/AllPhotos ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/image_db`

...it just gets the whole directory structure, even though the wget documentation says that wildcards are permitted in -I paths.

**Update 2:**

After further investigation, I am coming to the conclusion that I should probably write my own mirroring utility, although I still suspect I am approaching lftp the wrong way, and that there's a way to make it mirror only files that have a specific string in the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

One solution :

```
curl -s 'ftp://domain.tld/path' |
    awk '/^d.*regex/{print $NF}' |
    xargs wget -m ftp://domain.tld/path/
```

Or using `lftp` :

```
lftp -e 'ls; quit' 'ftp://domain.tld/path' |
    awk '/^d.*regex/{print $NF}' |
    xargs -I% lftp -e "mirror -e %; quit" ftp://domain.tld/path/
```

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. It looks like it wants to use http auth rather than ftp auth, though. I'll have to test it, after I figure out how to install it on this Amazon EC2 instance I have running.

Comment: POST edited, no need `mech-dump`, simply using `curl` now... `curl` is `ftp` capable.

Comment: OK, among those three commands, I need

**lftp -e 'ls -R; quit' -u username,password 'ftp.example.com/image_db'** piped to awk, although I can't figure out the exact syntax. Not sure what {print $NF} is supposed to do, and the example above has some extraneous paths output. **awk '/^.*\/AllPhotos/'** outputs paths, but they all end with a colon.

Comment: Better provide sample output

Comment: Not sure how to format text in these comments.
<pre>
sampleoutput
</pre> - nope, that didn't work. Will have to create a new answer. One thing though, these directories are so large that wget (which is what I've been trying to use for mirroring) runs several hours just to get a directory listing of the whole tree, and the listing is a multi-megabyte text file.

Comment: In view of the length of time it takes to get a directory listing, and the size of the directory, and the fact that I am interested in only those paths with 'AllPhotos' in them, it might be best to hard code them in a list of lftp or wget mirror commands in a cron script. I am trying this with wget now, and noticing that it takes about three hours to download the smallest 'AllPhotos' directory. And that's between two pretty fast cloud servers (mine is on AWS). Looks like the whole script will run for more than 24 hours, so I'd have to be careful about scheduling it.

Comment: What I ended up using is writing a script using wget and its --mirror option, with a separate wget command for each individual branch in the directory tree I want to mirror. The downside is that it doesn't adapt to changes in the source's directory structure, but fortunately the chance of that happening is remote.